# Open file with external Intent/Application

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent, io

After creating a file in the app's `fileDirectory` I would like to open it with an external app like the Adobe Reader etc. To achive this I tried to use an `Intent` like in the code below.

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext());
java.io.File fileItem = new java.io.File(cw.getFilesDir() + "/sync/arbitraryFileName.extension");

MimeTypeMap myMime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
Intent newIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String fileExtension = StaticHelper.fileExt(((File) item).getFileName());
if (fileExtension != null) {
    String mimeType = myMime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(fileExtension);
    String bb = Uri.fromFile(fileItem).toString();
    newIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(fileItem), mimeType);
    newIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    try {
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(newIntent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no extension found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

But sadly this code does not work: The apps are always saying that the file does not exist - but in the device's ADB shell I can find the file with exactly the same path which is used in my code.
I have already added

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

in my code, but it did not help at all.

Answer (score 2):

Third-party apps do not have access to your app's portion of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Use something like `FileProvider` [to make this content available to other apps](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/16/how-publish-files-via-content-uri.html).

Also:

- Replace all occurrences of `getApplicationContext()` with `this` in your code shown above. Only use `getApplicationContext()` when you know **exactly why** you are using `getApplicationContext()`.
- Get rid of the `ContextWrapper`, as you do not need it.

Comment: Okay - where can I create files which can be accessed by external apps?

Comment: @FlashTek: Starting with Android 7.0, that's not really a practical option, as you cannot pass a `file` `Uri` (e.g., `Uri.fromFile()`) to other apps, once your `targetSdkVersion` is 24 or higher. You are welcome to store your content where it is presently. Use `FileProvider` to make this content available to other apps.